# How to create a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists. One is called 'Region' and another is called 'Products'. Region has 111 distinct values and Products has 1181 distinct values. I want to create a dataframe of each combination of products and region from these two lists.

For example, I want this type of dataframe made up of two list. Here, product has 2 values and region has 3 values.

```
 Pdts Region

0    A      X

1    B      X

2    A      Y

3    B      Y

4    A      Z

5    B      Z
```

I want this type of dataframe but my 'Region' list has 111 distinct values and 'Products' list has 1181 distinct values. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would use `itertools.product(('A', 'B'), ('X', 'Y'))` to create normal list with Cartesian product and later convert it to `DataFrame`

Comment: Hi @furas, thanks for the solution. It is done.

Answer (score 1):

That's a Cartesian product

```
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dataframe1': ['A', 'B']})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dataframe2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']})

    # Assign new columns to a DataFrame
    # Merge with a database-style join
    # Drop specified labels from rows or columns
    product_df = df1.assign(key=1)\
        .merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key')\
        .drop('key', 1)

    print(product_df)
```

Output

```
    dataframe1 dataframe2
    0          A          X
    1          A          Y
    2          A          Z
    3          B          X
    4          B          Y
    5          B          Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Region': first_list, 'Products': second_list}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya mean:

```
>>> df['Region'] = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] * (len(df) // 3)
>>> df
  Pdts Region
0    A      X
1    B      Y
2    A      Z
3    B      X
4    A      Y
5    B      Z
>>>
```